# Department has Maximum Staff

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Write a query to display the name of the department that has the maximum staff count order by department name.

This is the schema of my problem:

[image: college management system]

I tried this:

```
select d.department_name
from   department d
       inner join staff s on d.department_id=s.department_id
group by d.department_name
having count(s.staff_id) >= all
       ( select count(s.staff_id) as cnt
         from   department d
                inner join staff s on d.department_id=s.department_id
         group by department_name )
order by d.department_name desc;
```

and I was able to pass one test case which results in 'SE' department, but I wasn't able to pass another test case.I don't know what second testcase want. I am not sure what I have done wrong in my code above.

Comment: Can you include the commands necessary to create your schema, populate the test data, the specifics of your test cases, and the results of your tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the windows function as follows:

```
select department_name, cnt
from
(select department_name, rank() over (order by cnt desc) as rn, cnt 
from
(select d.department_name, count(1) cnt
   from department d inner join staff s 
     on d.department_id=s.department_id
      group by d.department_name))
where rn = 1
order by department_name
```